# Android Deep linking not working without path attribute

Tags: android, deep-linking

I want to open app When user try to open website from android mobile and for that i am using Deep linking `

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="host name"
                android:path="/search" />
        </intent-filter>`
```

it working with **path** attribute but it not working without **path** attribute.

Comment: Does it work if path is ""?  If so, that should be good enough.

Comment: @Gabe Not working with "' in path

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE">/category>
        <data android:scheme="http"></data>
        <data android:scheme="https"></data>
        <data android:host="host"></data>
```